# How to open file from windows explorer in a new frame with emacsclient

Tags: microsoft-windows, frames, emacsclient

How do I achieve that files opened from Explorer with emacs are always opened in a new frame?

I tried making a link that has the target `<path/to/emacs/bin>/emacsclientw.exe --create-frame`. When I run that from `cmd` with a file argument it always opens a new frame as I expect it too.

However, when opening a file from the file explorer, either by the 'open-with' dialog on the link or by associating it with the link , emacs does create a new frame only if none exists at the moment. If a frame is already open every file I open after that gets opened in this frame, displaying the buffer of this file instead of the file buffer that was shown before.

My expected behavior of `--create-frame` would be that new frames are opened for each file when called from file explorer. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I wrote [a passage about how to use `emacsclient` on MS-Windows](https://github.com/shynur/.emacs.d/blob/main/docs/Emacs-use_daemon.md) before, but in Chinese, so you may need to use translation software. I think it does solve your problem; here's the [demo](https://github.com/shynur/misc/blob/main/tmp/pictures/create-frame.gif).

Answer (score 0):

The comment of demo contains the answer.  According to [the article](https://github.com/shynur/.emacs.d/blob/main/docs/Emacs-use_daemon.md) by @shynur,
to change the arguments of emacs when opening a file with it, one has to change the registry key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\emacsclientw.exe\shell\open\command` as described in the Windows documentation [Verbs and File Associations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-verbs#register-an-application-to-handle-arbitrary-file-types).
So to add the `--create-frame` argument to the open action one needs to:

1. Open any file with emacsclientw.exe to create the registry entry
2. Add `--create-frame` to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\emacsclientw.exe\shell\open\command` default key, changing it from

> "C:\Users\evilsetg\Desktop\emacs\bin\emacsclientw.exe" "%1"

to

> "C:\Users\evilsetg\Desktop\emacs\bin\emacsclientw.exe"
> "--create-frame" "%1"